# Illustrator Width tool: edit multiple points simultaneously

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

Is it possible, using the Width tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>), to change the width of a path at two (or more) points simultaneously? I am trying to adjust the width of a closed path symmetrically, by working on two opposite points at a time.

I have tried [working with half of the path and then mirroring it and joining it](https://shapeshed.com/drawing-symmetrical-shapes-in-illustrator/), but unfortunately, the Width tool produces different results when a path is incomplete. (See my attempts below.)

For more context, here's the path I'm working with:

[image: The path I need to change the width of symmetrically.]

Thank you!

##### Current attempts

As mentioned above, I have tried working on points on a half path and then mirroring the path, but the results are not satisfactory. Additionally, the two resulting paths cannot be merged, because merging paths with different width profiles does not merge the width profiles properly.

I approximated the "expected result" by repeatedly adjusting a point on the left and one on the right (enabling "Adjust Adjoining Width Points"), but this approach is suboptimal because it requires adjusting the same points at least 10–20 times.

[image: Result of applying the Width tool on a half path and an approximation of the expected result.]

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you! I updated my question to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the problem, I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Actually, I just discovered it is possible to select two control points by holding down <kbd>shift</kbd>, but they are quite tricky to select - you need to do it with the Width tool. Select one, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select another - and I'm not sure it would really solve your problem anyway.  You can kind of get rid of the pinch effect by double clicking the width point, breaking the aspect ratio lock, and adjusting it numerically to limit it to the outside of the stroke (see the dialog below), but it takes quite a bit of tweaking, and I suspect you'd need more width points to control it effectively.

Anyway, here's how I would do it, in a simpler fashion

1. Draw one side of the symmetrical shape, use the Transform Effect to reflect it.
2. Do *Object > Expand Appearance*.
3. Join the two paths at the end anchors, so you have one complete joined path.
4. Apply the width control point to one side (on top of an anchor). Double clicking with the Width Tool will allow you to enter the width numerically. Do the same on the other side.

You might also be able to use the "Adjust Adjoinging Width Points" option, but success may depend on your construction. Perhaps try it and see, although for me it kind of messes up with just two width points. Perhaps you'd need three?  Don't know what's up with that.

[image]

Finished result

[image]